# Creating Elastic Beanstalk Application failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Creating Elastic Beanstalk Application on AWS failed with GRAY color in health and errors as bellow, I couldn't move forward.

WARN: Environment health has been set to RED

ERROR: Cannot update ELB target group when there is no ELB in the group resources

ERROR: Creating security group named: awseb-e-securitygroupname-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-THEIDOFYOURSECURTYGROUP failed Reason: Resource creation cancelled

ERROR: Stack named 'awseb-e-somename-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBV2LoadBalancer, AWSEBSecurityGroup]

ERROR: Creating load balancer failed Reason: You cannot provide subnets from multiple locales. (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancing; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID:[the id]; Proxy:null)

Comment: Create new one, or it fails for all cases?

Comment: I tried to create a new one by removing the failed, but the same error appears again.

Comment: Can you go to cloudformation, and check events for the EB stack. Maybe it has more info.

Comment: Thank you for your follow up question and help. in cloud formation events. 1. CREATE_FAILED You cannot provide subnets from multiple locales. (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancing; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: ZZZZZZZZZ; Proxy: null). 2. CREATE_FAILED Resource creation cancelled and 3. CREATE_FAILED The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBV2LoadBalancer, AWSEBSecurityGroup].

Comment: So it seems that there is something wrong with the subnets that you want to use for the EB.

Comment: You are right, I went my subnets and fixed it. Marcin, Thank you so much. I don't remember when I did it but I added two additional subnets with out real need. Removing those two additional subnets fixed the Issue. Multiple times, before now I reached the same place and I was not sure about the need to remove them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was identified by going to **CloudFormation console** and checking the `Events` tab of the EB stack that failed to deploy. The error found was:

> You cannot provide subnets from multiple locales

Based on this it was inferred that the there are two many subnets used for the EB environment. Removal of the extra subnets was the **solution** to the problem.